# TSLint: Custom error message on existing rule

Tags: angular, typescript, eslint, tslint

I would like to use the rule [no-console](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-console/) of ts-lint, with some custom error message.

The idea is to give developpers a more user friendly output, and make them use our tools for logging instead of console.

Instead of something like this

```
> npm run lint
ERROR: src/app/app.component.ts:84:5 - Calls to 'console.info' are not allowed.
```

I wish to have this

```
> npm run lint
ERROR: src/app/app.component.ts:84:5 - Calls to 'console.info' are not allowed.
You should only use console.log for local development, and you have probably forgotten
to remove this line.
If you want to have logs on production or preproduction, please use instead the
`Logger` class. To know more about this Logger, please refer to this documentation <link>.
```

Any idea if it's possible ? And how to do that ?

Thanks !